# How to generate a list of outputs for function f(x,y) for a set of known (x,y) values

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I want a list of outputs the function f(x,y)=x+y will give for x,y values of (1,5),(5,3),(0,2),(1,1),(2,6). How do I do that? I know this must be pretty straight forward. I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance

---

```
In[81]:=f[x_, y_] = x + y;
vals = {{1, 5}, {5, 3}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 6}};
f[#] & /@ vals

Out[83]:={f[{1, 5}], f[{5, 3}], f[{0, 2}], f[{1, 1}], f[{2, 6}]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Ok I got it. I use an older version. That must be it!

```
f[{x_, y_}] = x + y;
vals = {{1, 5}, {5, 3}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 6}};
f[#] & /@ vals
{6, 8, 2, 2, 8}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica there a number of ways to do things. For illustration and contemplation using the example: all the  following produce the desired result (though I am not at all suggesting some of them and many are just the same thing written in a different way):

```
f @@@ vals
f @@ # & /@ vals
Apply[f, #] & /@ vals
f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ vals
f@(Sequence @@ #) & /@ vals
Composition[f, Sequence @@ # &][#] & /@ vals
ReplacePart[#, 0 -> f] & /@ vals
```

I suggest looking at the documentation, the Qand A here, and  playing.

Answer (score 2):

So first we will start off by defining our function.

```
f[x_, y_] = x + y;
```

So this takes pairs of values and then adds them together. We could make it more specific by specifying what the variables need to be (Integers, Real Numbers, etc), but this is good enough for our purposes. If you are asking how we can use this, then we can introduce numbers into it like so:

```
In[13]:= f[1, 3]

Out[13]= 4
```

But if you are asking how we can generate a list of output, then we can implement a Pure Function.

```
In[20]:= vals = {{1, 5}, {5, 3}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 6}};

In[25]:= f[#] & /@ vals

Out[25]= {6, 8, 2, 2, 8}
```

We first stored our sets of values as a list of points (x,y). Then we took our function and mapped all of these pairs across. So out output is returned as a list of the function values.

If this is not what you were looking for, or if you want any more clarification, then I am all ears!

Note that Pure Functions are a very powerful feature of the language!

Edit--

I see now that there was a legacy definition of f that I forgot about.

Namely that I defined

```
f[{x_,y_}]:=x+y;
```

and forgot to write that I defined it. Sorry for the confusion! Good luck in learning the language! Use the documentation and this site for help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: In[]=f[x_, y_] = x + y;
vals = {{1, 5}, {5, 3}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 6}};
f[#] & /@ vals

Out[]={f[{1, 5}], f[{5, 3}], f[{0, 2}], f[{1, 1}], f[{2, 6}]}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first line of your code should be `f[{x_, y_}] = x + y;`.  Alternatively, you can use `f[x_] := Total[x]`.

Comment: `f` does not take a `List` as an argument. You need to `Map` an `Apply` with `f @@ # & /@ vals` which can be abbreviated as  `f @@@ vals`.

Answer (score 1):

```
vals = {{1, 5}, {5, 3}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 6}};
```

Here are three common ways to solve your problem.

`Map` with `Part`.

```
f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ vals
```

> {6, 8, 2, 2, 8}

`MapThread` and `Transpose`.

```
MapThread[f, Transpose @ vals]
```

> {6, 8, 2, 2, 8}

Define a second version of `f` which takes advantage of *Mathematica*'s pattern matching to perform argument destructuring.

```
f[{x_, y_}] := f[x, y]
f /@ vals
```

> {6, 8, 2, 2, 8}

You now have the best of both worlds; you do not loose the original `f`.

```
f[2, 3]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```